# Sum columns in pandas only if exists else 0

Tags: python, pandas, sum, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```
  GULOSS         GRLoss

    1             1
    2             2
    3             3
```

I want to sum in such a way that I Get

```
  GULOSS         GRLoss       Post

    6             6            0
```

where Post does not exist in initial dataframe and Post is required in final dataframe with condition that if it does not exist then make the sum for the non existing column as 0

Comment: Here it comes: What have you tried?

Comment: data = pd.read_csv(filename,  encoding='utf-16')
data.columns = pd.Series(data.columns).str.replace(' ', '')


datasum = data[['GUPLoss', 'GRLoss','POST']].sum()

Comment: I need to add some condition on POST column as it does not exist

Comment: Your question makes little sense, please show in your question the logic for the new 'Post' column, what does throw 0 mean here?

Comment: KeyError: "['POST'] not in index"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, here's how I would do it:

```
if 'POST' not in data.columns:
    data['POST'] = 0

datasum = data.sum()
```